# Bash script for linux to create 5 new files

Tags: linux, bash

I need help in creating a bash script. I want the script to create 5 new files each time I run it.

I tried a basic for loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..5}
do
  touch File${i}
done
```

Obviously, it only creates 5 files named `File1` to `File5`. I need it to make 5 new files with new names each time I run the script. any tips in what direction to look for?

Comment: Right now im trying to save the output from counting the number of files in the directory to a string.

Comment: Sorry guys, I made it unclear in my question. To make it clear, I want it to go like : first run - it creates File1 to File5. Second run : File 6 to file 10. and so on. Right now i have saved the output of ls | wc -l to a string. I am now trying to use this string as a starting number for the loop, but it doesnt work. P.S I also cant seem to edit the original question for some reason

Answer (score 1):

No need to use loop. Simply do this

```
touch File{1..5}
```

To create new files each time based on range

```
START=$(ls | wc -l)
END=$((START+1))
for((i=START;i<=END;i++)); do  
    touch File$i
```

Comment: While this is a more efficient way to do what the code in the question does … it doesn't address the question (which is about creating *new* files each time and not just updating the same five files).

Comment: @Quentin; I missed that part. I added the solution now.

Comment: I think the question is trying to ask how to programmatically determine a number to start from.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to determine a number to start from for creating the new files. So far ive done a string that saves the output of ls | wc -l. I now want to use this to create the files but cant get it to work

Comment: @Testonjumbk; It is not clear in your question. You should add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was given before it became clear that the names were to be consecutive and following on from the previous run. I will let it stand rather than delete it as it is potentially informative for other, future readers.

How about with `mktemp`:

```
mktemp {a..e}XXXXXX
```

**Sample Output**

```
aW1KLgp
bZrPq2I
c1BKn8i
dIjzxrc
ezpWkkO
```

That will give you one file beginning with `a`, one beginning with `b` and so on.

Or you may prefer this:

```
mktemp {1..5}-XXXXXX
1-00r8Gf
2-wjojeF
3-lPni6G
4-ihYrOP
5-B5YtEB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(ls File* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
for ((i=$count+1; i<=$count+5; i++)); do
    touch $(printf "File%03d" $i)
done
```

Explanations:

Here I assume the files start with prefix "File".

The line `count=$(ls ...)` counts how many files which start with "File" exist in the directory. The part `2>/dev/null` works to suppress the error message when there is no such a file on the initial execution.
Then the `for` loop generates additional five files accordingly. You can modify the number in `%03d` depending on how many files you are going to produce.

Comment: Right.  I've added an explanation about that.

Answer (score 0):

While some of the other suggestions use `ls` piped to `wc` this isn't guaranteed to be correct, see [here.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Instead you can get the number of files in your current directory as such:

```
files=( * )  
num_files=${#files[@]}  
if [[ $files=='*' ]]; then  
    touch File{000..004}
    exit
fi
for (( i=num_files; i<num_files+5; i++)); do  
    touch $( printf "File%03d" $i )
done
```

A quick breakdown on what each part does:
    `files=( * )` Uses pattern matching to get all the files in your current directory, even if they contain newlines. The `( )` means to make an array from those files and assign it to `files`.

`${#files[@]}` will give the number of elements in the array `files`, aka how many files are in your directory.

The if block checks if `files` is litterally `*`, which means there were no files to match, aka you were in an empty directory, in which case it will create the first 5 files for you.
Otherwise you iterate over the next 5 file numbers.

`touch $( printf "File$03d" $i )` executes that `printf` in a subshell, which will return the name File followed by a 3 digit number with leading zeroes, so that your files will be sorted how you would expect.

Also you were off by one in your question; {0..5} gives you six numbers, not five.

Hope this helps!

Edit 0:

As Mark said below, using `shopt -s nullglob` will cause the wildcard to return nothing if it doesn't match any files, which is the desired behavior here.

Here's the updated solution:

```
shopt -s nullglob  
files=( * )  
num_files=${#files[@]}  
for (( i=num_files; i<num_files+5; i++)); do  
    touch $( printf "File%03d" $i )
done
```

Comment: Have a look at `shopt -s nullglob`  and you can remove lines 2-5.